# Wordpress post content not showing

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress blog hosted on IIS. Everything was working fine until I moved the blog from a subdomain to a subfolder.

I left the blog at the same physical location and created a virtual directory.

Now the backend seems to be working just fine. I can edit posts and everything.

In the blog itself I can see the main list of posts with the preview of the post content, but when I click to enter the post, only the title is displayed.
I don't know much about PHP (.net for me) and I don't really know where to start.

I tried switching themes and got the same results.

Thank you!

Comment: As @Interrobang said, go to your General settings and update the two url fields to your current url.

Comment: This is off topic for SO. Try wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @skjaidev - You might be right, but I was thinking this might be a PHP thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I would check would be WordPress's "Site Settings". There are two fields there where you can set the path to your blog, and the URL at which it can be reached. If you moved the WordPress folder, you'll need to update these fields.

Comment: shoosh I was one second too late... ;)

Comment: That was the first thing I did after the move. Thats not it.

Comment: In that case, the next step is to enable PHP error messages and see what error gets spit out, probably.

Comment: I'm bad with PHP, but I got errors showing and this lead me to the problematic plugin. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any cache plugin ? If so then go for deactivating this plugin like w3 total cache and then again update the URL's of wordpress blog. Hope that it will help you

Comment: What do you mean by "update the URLs"? Could you please give some more details?